# How to switch old-passwords OFF in Mysql 4.1

Tags: mysql, passwords

I am having a hard time migrating my MySQL 4.1 database from old 16-byte password hashes to the new 41-byte hashes. The problem is, that the mysqld server automatically starts with the "old-passwords = on" directive, which restricts setting new passwords to 41-bytes length.

My question: Does anyone know how I can tell mysqld to run without the "old-passwords = on" directive? I tried my.ini, commmandline, setting the variable locally, but nothing worked.

Thanks a lot!
Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to check is the width of the `user` table `Password` field in the mysql database.  Prior to 4.1 this was 16 characters wide.  When upgrading to 4.1 the width should have been changed to 41 characters by means of the `mysql_upgrade` utility provided.  If that step was missed for some reason the server would default to using the old 16-byte hashes, which is the behaviour you describe.

There's a [write up](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/password-hashing.html) of this in the MySQL docs.

If you find that your table does need to be updated from char(16) to char(41) and you have the mysql_update utility, run that to complete the upgrade.  Alternatively (take a backup and then you can) update manually using:

```
ALTER TABLE user
MODIFY Password char(41) character set latin1 collate latin1_bin NOT NULL default ''
```

Comment: Thanks martin,

updating the password length as you mentioned was also a necessary step to solve my problem, but not the only one.

I found out that I had to set the flag "old-password=0" in my my.ini config file. It is very important to set this option in the correct section of the ini-file. Section names seem to correspond with windows service names: In my case, the windows service name is "MySQL4" - unfortunately this section had to be manually created, as the default name after setup seems to be "mysqld".

All the best!